# Logo Background Zoom Without Making Logo Zoom

Tags: html, css, background, hover, effect

The logo which I am using in my header has no background, but I added a background for when the logo is hovered over. 
I wanted the logo BACKGROUND to zoom in, but the code I am using makes the LOGO zoom in and not the background...
How can I change the code to make the logo BACKGROUND zoom in without effecting the logo?? 
I've genuinely been trying for weeks... Any help would be appreciated.

**CSS**

```
.cento-header .logo,
.cento-header .logo a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
}

/**hover**/

.cento-header .logo a:hover img {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  background: #000;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 </head>
<body class='tall-header-page  wsite-theme-light'>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="cento-header">
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="logo">{logo}</div>
    <label class="hamburger"><span></span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav desktop-nav">{menu}</div>
    </div><!-- end .container -->
  </div><!-- end .nav-wrap -->
</div><!-- end .header -->  

<div class="banner-wrap wsite-background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="banner">
      <h2>{headline:text global="false"}</h2>
      <p>{headline-paragraph:text global="false"}</p>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end banner-wrap -->

<div class="content-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main-wrap">{content}</div>
  </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end main-wrap -->

<div class="light-blue-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    {light-blue-wrap:content  global="false"}
  </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end light-blue-post -->

 <div class="banner-wrap2 wsite-background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="banner">
      <h2>{headline:text global="false"}</h2>
      <p>{headline-paragraph:text global="false"}</p>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end banner-wrap2 -->

    <div class="usable-one-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    {usable-one-wrap:content  global="false"}
  </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end usable-one-post -->

<div class="footer-wrap">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="footer">{footer}</div>
    </div><!-- end container -->
  </div><!-- end footer-wrap -->
 </div>

 <div class="nav mobile-nav">{menu}</div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/plugins.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well as your CSS.

Comment: My website link is: www.gooodsketch.weebly.com I think that could help to explain what I mean more, just hover over the logo and you'll know what I mean then

Comment: I'm sort of hoping it to look like the logo on this site when you hover over it... www.zoella.co.uk

Comment: Basically, I would like the black background to appear whilst zooming on when you hover over the logo :) pleeeeaaase help me!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any html but from your question i have created a scenario to help you out with your problem
Have a look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f7v0frmy/ 
All i did is made a reusable class called `.anim-Gah img` with targeting a img under it as a child element. So necessary html will be like

```
<div class="container orwhatever anim-Gah">
  <img src="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2mypiS48E1qzex9io1_1280.jpg">
</div>
```

and the css for that is

```
.anim-Gah img {
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out
}

.anim-Gah:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05)
}
```

for your logo, just put outside of that anim-gah class and play with position whatever way you'd like. Mind that z-index though mentioned in jsfiddle ;)
Cheers!

Comment: thank you so much for trying but it still is not working how I was hoping for it to work, I sort of wanted it to look like the logo on this site when you hover over it... www.zoella.co.uk     my site is: www.gooodsketch.weebly.com